# Tell ParallelMap[] to use just specific kernels

Tags: parallelization

Is there a way to tell `ParallelMap` to use just some specific kernels (as is possible for `ParallelEvaluate`)?

**Background:** I have 6 local and 16 remote kernels. During some analysis I call `ParalleMap` twice. One `ParallelMap` is quicker using all the kernels, but one is actually slower (probably bandwidth limited). This is why I would like to run one `ParallelMap` on all the kernels and the other only on the local kernels. I don't want to close the kernels in between if possible. I also tried setting the parallelization method to `"CoarsestGrained"` or `"FinestGrained"`, but that didn't help much.

**Edit:**

Could somebody shed light on why the following does not work?

```
num = 10;
list = Range[num];
function = Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &;
ParallelMap[function, list]
aKer = Kernels[];
Block[{Parallel`Protected`$kernels = aKer[[{2, 3}]]},
   ParallelMap[function, list]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second map is still run on 4 of the Kernels instead of just two.
I traced `ParallelMap` to

```
Parallel`Developer`ParallelDispatch[Parallel`Combine`Private`cmdl]
```

and

```
Parallel`Developer`ParallelDispatch[Parallel`Parallel`Private`cmds_] :=
    Parallel`Developer`ParallelDispatch[Parallel`Parallel`Private`cmds,Kernels[]]
Kernels[]:=Parallel`Protected`$kernels
```

so overriding `` Parallel`Protected`$kernels `` should in theory work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me give a different approach. One downside of WalkingRandomly's approach is, that he distributes the whole `list` over all subkernels. The he uses `Part` in each subcall to select the data to use.  I will make this differently:

- I divide the `data` into chunks and define each chunk as `subdata` on every subkernel you want to use in the current call
- then I can simply call `Map[f,subdata]` on each wanted subkernel with `ParallelEvaluate`

The `chunkenize` works whether `Length[data]` is divisible by the number of used kernels or not.

```
chunkenize[data_, nkernels_] := 
 Partition[data, UpTo[Ceiling[Length[data] / nkernels]]]

MyParallelMap[f_, data_, kernels_] := 
 Module[{chunks = chunkenize[data, Length[kernels]]},
  Block[{subdata},
   MapIndexed[
    ParallelEvaluate[subdata = #1, kernels[[First[#2]]]] &, chunks];
   DistributeDefinitions[f];
   ParallelEvaluate[Map[f, subdata], kernels]
   ]
  ]
```

Trying it gives

```
data = Range[20];
f[x_] := {$KernelID, x^2}
kernels = LaunchKernels[];

MyParallelMap[f, data, kernels]
(*
{{{1,1},{1,4},{1,9},{1,16},{1,25}},{{2,36},{2,49},{2,64},{2,81},{2,100}},
{{3,121},{3,144},{3,169},{3,196},{3,225}},{{4,256},{4,289},{4,324},{4,361},{4,400}}}
*)
```

Or if you like

```
MyParallelMap[f,data,kernels[[{2,3}]]]
(*
{{{2,1},{2,4},{2,9},{2,16},{2,25},{2,36},{2,49},{2,64},{2,81},{2,100}},
{{3,121},{3,144},{3,169},{3,196},{3,225},{3,256},{3,289},{3,324},{3,361},{3,400}}}
*)
```

### Update

> Also I would really like to know why overriding `` Parallel`Protected`$kernels `` does not work.

When you trace the output of a simple `ParallelMap` call, you can investigate what happens. What I did is, I created a full trace output and checked then, on what positions the subkernels like `KernelObject[1, "local"]` appear.

In detail this meant to check the `FullForm` of a subkernel because then you see that it has the form

```
Parallel`Kernels`kernel[....]
```

then I launched some kernels and trace the output. Using `Position` you can find all positions which match a sub-kernel

```
kernels = LaunchKernels[];
trace = Trace[ParallelMap[$KernelID &, Range[100]]];
pos = Position[trace, Parallel`Kernels`kernel, Infinity];
```

If you now inspect a bit the positions where the sub-kernels arise, you first find what you found: `` Parallel`Protected`$kernels ``. But soon you see

```
Part[trace,Sequence@@Drop[pos[[10]], -4]]
(*
{Parallel`Protected`$sortedkernels,
 {KernelObject[1,local],KernelObject[2,local],
  KernelObject[3,local],KernelObject[4,local]}}
*)
```

This brings us to the following solution:

```
Block[{
  $KernelCount = 2,
  Parallel`Protected`$sortedkernels = Take[kernels, 2]
  },
 ParallelMap[$KernelID &, Range[100]]
]
(*
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}
*)
```

Since I didn't find this that quick, I had time to do some more spelunking. You may have noted, that I set `$KernelCount` in the `Block`. This is, because the value of it is used for the partitionizer.

Comment: Yep. That's a better way to do it :)

Comment: @WalkingRandomly Nevertheless you had already the basic idea. And keeping in mind that you are a *newbie* who made 215 reps yesterday and writes his answers with clear code-boxes and images, I can just repeat: I'm very glad to have you here.

Comment: thanks :)  I find it interesting seeing how other people solve the same problem.  I'm off to bed now. 1am here

Comment: Actually..one more thing.  It would have never have occured to me to use a `Block[]` within a Module. In fact, I never use Block[].  May I ask why you use it here? Why not just do `MyParallelMap[f_, data_, kernels_] := 
 Module[{chunks = chunkenize[data, Length[kernels]], subdata}, 
  MapIndexed[ParallelEvaluate[subdata = #1, kernels[[First[#2]]]] &, 
   chunks];
  DistributeDefinitions[f];
  ParallelEvaluate[Map[f, subdata], kernels]]`

Comment: @WalkingRandomly In this case it works without `Block` because `ParallelEvaluate` has the `HoldFirst` attribute. I just like to make sure (even for the reader) that `subdata` is a new, local variable which should not interfere with any globally defined `subdata`. The difference between `Block` and `Module` is the scoping type: First uses *dynamic scoping* the latter *lexical scopying*

Comment: Thanks for that.  Will google dynamic scoping and lexical scoping tomorrow :)  Cheers..

Comment: Supposing one had to evaluate `MyParallelMap[f,data, kernel]` several times, how could this code be optimized in case `data` were a fixed quantity, and the function `f` were constantly changing?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that you can do this with `ParallelMap` directly (well, I can't find anything in the documentation at least) but you could emulate such behaviour using ParallelEvaluate.  Consider the following example and its output on my quad core laptop

```
num=10;
list = Range[num];
function = Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &;
ParallelMap[function, list]
```

[image: Result of evaluating the above code]

The goal of this function is just to frame the input with the $KernelID of the kernel that did the framing printed underneath.  Imagine that kernels {3,4} were broken and so I only wanted to work with kernels {1,2}

```
num = 10;
list = Range[num];
function = Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &;
wantedkernels = {1, 2};
chunk = num/Length[wantedkernels];
DistributeDefinitions[chunk, list, function];

ParallelEvaluate[
  Map[function, 
   list[[1 + ($KernelID - 1)*chunk ;; ($KernelID*chunk)]]],
  wantedkernels] // Flatten
```

[image: The result of the above code]

Performance might suffer from the fact that each kernel gets a fixed amount of work (so no load balancing etc) but perhaps this is enough for your needs?

Comment: One pitfall here is that kernel IDs don't necessarily start at 1. Just run `LaunchKernels[];CloseKernels[];LaunchKernels[]`. Also losing the load balancing is a major blow. But I appreciated the general idea and will try it out (+1).

Comment: Agreed.  I only intended to show the basic principal.  halirutan's answer uses the same basic idea as mine but is  more robust and probably more efficient.  Even his solution,howerver, would need more work before it became something that would be fit for general usage.