# ParallelDo barely faster than Do

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, iteration

I am new to parallel computing, so I am trying to get a grasp as to how this works. Many posts seem to indicate that overhead (like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136697/parallel-calculation-is-5-times-slower-than-the-non-parallel-one)) is a common pitfall, but I do not see why this would be the case here.
Here are the following two codes, one using Do, and the other ParallelDo

Set-up:

```
lmax = 5;
expr =((1 + f0)*q*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ])/(Sqrt[f0]*r0) - 
      ((Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + f0*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ])*
      (2*q*Cos[θ]^2 - q*Sin[θ]^2))/(Sqrt[f0]*r0) + 
      ((-1 + f0)*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ]*(q*Cos[θ]^2*Cos[ϕ]^2 - 
      2*q*Cos[ϕ]^2*Sin[θ]^2 + q*Sin[ϕ]^2))/(Sqrt[f0]*r0) + 
      (2*Sqrt[f0]*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ]*(q*Cos[ϕ]^2 + 
      q*Cos[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ]^2 - 2*q*Sin[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ]^2))/r0;
```

Do code:

```
result = Table[0, {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}];
(Do[result[[l + 1, m + 1]] = 
    Integrate[(expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ]), 
       {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}], {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}]) // AbsoluteTiming
 result  // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

On my computer, this takes about ~50 seconds.

ParallelDo code:

```
result = Table[0, {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}];
SetSharedVariable[result]
(ParallelDo[result[[l + 1, m + 1]] = 
    Integrate[(expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ]), 
       {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}], {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}]) // AbsoluteTiming
 result  // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

This takes ~37 seconds. I have `$ProcessorCount = 4`, and Mathematica sets `$KernelCount=4` by default when I ask it to parallelize something. why is the gain so little? Is there a way to make the computation faster?

---

Running the modified code proposed by @ShinKim answer, the computation is in my case barely  faster; about ~ 31 seconds.

Following the advice of @HenrikSchumacher and @SjoerdSmit, I attempted:

```
(result = ParallelTable[
Integrate[(expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] 
Sin[θ]), {θ, 0, π}, 
{ϕ, 0, 2 π}], {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

This also takes ~39 seconds to complete.

Note: I always use `Quit[]` before trying each piece of code for a fair comparison.

Comment: Sharing the variable `result` is maybe not a good idea...

Comment: Like @HenrikSchumacher says: using a shared variable basically defeats the point of parallelisation. Use `ParallelTable` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, using a better algorithm vastly beats parallelization.

Define a function that integrates trigonometric functions over the sphere: using pattern matching instead of `Integrate`,

```
sphericalintegrate[a_] := 
  2π^2 Expand[TrigToExp[a]] /. {E^(u_ θ + v_ ϕ) -> 0,
                                E^(v_ ϕ) -> 0,
                                E^(u_ θ) /; OddQ[u/I] -> -2/(π u),
                                E^(u_ θ) -> 0}
```

Let's compare:

```
computeresult[l_, m_] := Integrate[
  expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2π}]

fastcomputeresult[l_, m_] := sphericalintegrate[
  expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ]]

lmax = 5;
result = Table[computeresult[l, m], {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(*    30.8732    *)

fastresult = Table[fastcomputeresult[l, m], {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(*    0.922231    *)

result == fastresult // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: (-1) Could you double-check the code? I copy-pasted but `result` and `fastresult` are not identical, not to mention `fastresult // FullSimplify` takes more than 5 mins to complete

Comment: The formula should work but kept not working, but the problem was that `expr` had $\phi$ not $\varphi$. I'll retract (-1) once it's corrected :)

Comment: Oops, sorry! fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

Reduce the sizes of computation 'chunks' to distribute the workload more optimally by defining index set:

```
ind = Flatten[Table[{l, m}, {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}], 1];
result = Table[0, {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}];
SetSharedVariable[result];
ParallelDo[
    {l, m} = ind[[i]];
    result[[l + 1, m + 1]] = Integrate[
        (expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]])
    , {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
, {i, Length@ind}] // AbsoluteTiming
ClearAll[ind];

(* {27.4837, Null} *)
```

This makes it about <del>7.6 times</del> only $\times 2$ faster. My PC is nothing fancy, but has `$ProcessorCount = 4` and `$KernelCount = 8`.

---

**UPDATE.** I can confirm the 'caching' behavior in @Michael's answer. Here I improved the parallelization that gives consistent performance independent of caching. First, `FullSimplify`ing the `expr`(in fact I just used `expr*Sin[θ]`) apparently cuts down the computation time in half. Also I further reduced the computation size by separating the integration domains w.r.t. the variables:

```
CloseKernels[];LaunchKernels[];
lmax = 5;
expr = ((1 + f0)*q*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ])/(Sqrt[f0]*r0) -
       ((Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + f0*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ])*(2*q*Cos[θ]^2 - q*Sin[θ]^2))/(Sqrt[f0]*r0) +
       ((-1 + f0)*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ]*(q*Cos[θ]^2*Cos[ϕ]^2 - 2*q*Cos[ϕ]^2*Sin[θ]^2 + q*Sin[ϕ]^2))/(Sqrt[f0]*r0) +
       (2*Sqrt[f0]*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ]*(q*Cos[ϕ]^2 + q*Cos[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ]^2 - 2*q*Sin[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ]^2))/r0;
expr = FullSimplify[expr*Sin[θ]];


(*prep for parallelization*)
ind = RandomSample@Flatten[Table[{l, m}, {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}], 1];
comps1 = {};
comps2 = {};
SetSharedVariable[comps1, comps2];


(*parallel compute*)
ParallelDo[
    {l, m} = ind[[i]];
    val = Integrate[(expr*SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ]), {θ, 0, Pi}];
    AppendTo[comps1, {l + 1, m + 1, val}];
, {i, Length@ind}] // AbsoluteTiming;
t1 = First@%;
ParallelDo[
    {l, m, func} = comps1[[i]];
    val = Integrate[func, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}];
    AppendTo[comps2, {l, m, val}];
, {i, Length@ind}] // AbsoluteTiming;
First@% + t1

(* 10.0961 *)


(*make result*)
result = GatherBy[Sort[comps2], First][[All, All, 3]];
result // Simplify // MatrixForm

ClearAll[ind,comps1,comps2,t1];
```

This makes it about 5 times faster. IMHO this is an acceptable multiplier provided that `$KernelCount = 8`.

Answer (score 2):

*[System: V13.0.0, Mac M1 Max, 10 cores]*

You can observe a rough analysis with the menu command **Evaluation > Parallel Kernel Status...**.  We can do a bit better by timing each integral. It will be seen that the integrals take relatively long time, and the overhead of parallelization of just about any parallel setup won't be very significant. The real overhead cost here is the initialization of the `Integrate` code on each kernel. (If I run @ShinKim's `SharedVariable` method twice, the second run takes less than a second, unless I permute `ind`, in which case, it runs only a second or two faster than the original run. This shows, I think, that in addition to whatever initialization there is, results or parts of them are cached.) Since the longer integrals take 3-5s, a kernel that happens to get two such integrals might take 10s to get its job done, though in fact, as luck would have it, it's more like 8-9s. If you have only 4 kernels, then some are going to get 4 integrals, maybe four long ones.

Now, the interesting part is the cacheing. I don't know what is cached (or perhaps just autoloaded and initialized).  If we do the same analysis on the unparallelized integrations, we see only a couple of long integrals and the rest are faster.  Thus, in parallelizing, we lose the benefit of this cacheing (if that is what it is).

Before each run:

```
Quit[]

LaunchKernels[];

lmax = 4; (* reduced to save time :) *)
expr = ((1 + f0)*q*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ])/(Sqrt[f0]*r0) - 
       ((Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + f0*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ]) *
         (2*q*Cos[θ]^2 - q*Sin[θ]^2)) / 
         (Sqrt[f0]*r0) + 
       ((-1 + f0)*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ] * 
         (q*Cos[θ]^2*Cos[ϕ]^2 - 
          2*q*Cos[ϕ]^2*Sin[θ]^2 + 
          q*Sin[ϕ]^2)) / (Sqrt[f0]*r0) + 
       (2*Sqrt[f0]*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ] * 
         (q*Cos[ϕ]^2 + 
          q*Cos[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ]^2 - 
          2*q*Sin[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ]^2)) / r0;
```

With `ParallelTable` (no `SharedVariable`). Only the outer loop is parallelized, which means one kernel gets 5 integrals (and more of the longer ones):

```
(times = Flatten[
    ParallelTable[
     (Integrate[expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ],
       {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}];
     $KernelID) // 
      AbsoluteTiming,
     {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}],
    1]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{16.955, {{1.0218, 10}, {1.05096, 9}, {4.39347, 9}, {1.08692, 
   8}, {4.31533, 8}, {3.46061, 8}, {1.0968, 7}, {4.706, 7}, {3.45951, 
   7}, {3.59418, 7}, {1.05576, 6}, {4.38848, 6}, {3.4545, 
   6}, {3.47644, 6}, {3.29451, 6}}}
*)

Merge[Apply[Rule]@*Reverse /@ times, List]
Total@*Flatten /@ %
(*  $KernelID -> times of integrals (not all kernels used)
<|10 -> {{1.0218}},
   9 -> {{1.05096, 4.39347}}, 
   8 -> {{1.08692, 4.31533, 3.46061}}, 
   7 -> {{1.0968,  4.706,   3.45951, 3.59418}}, 
   6 -> {{1.05576, 4.38848, 3.4545,  3.47644, 3.29451}}|>

<|10 -> 1.0218, 9 -> 5.44443, 8 -> 8.86287, 7 -> 12.8565, 6 -> 15.6697|>
*)
```

@ShinKim's method with `SharedVariable`; the table just returns the time and kernel of each result.

```
ind = Flatten[Table[{l, m}, {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}], 1];
result = Table[0, {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}];
SetSharedVariable[result];
(times = ParallelTable[
    ({l, m} = ind[[i]];
      result[[l + 1, m + 1]] = 
       Integrate[expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ],
        {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}];
      $KernelID) // 
     AbsoluteTiming,
    {i, Length@ind}]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{9.12166, {{1.3988, 10}, {0.336149, 10}, {5.10557, 9}, {0.597471, 
   9}, {5.03329, 8}, {3.36767, 8}, {1.4241, 7}, {4.75394, 
   7}, {4.78472, 6}, {3.54514, 6}, {1.44249, 5}, {5.10244, 
   4}, {4.73389, 3}, {4.82558, 2}, {4.79167, 1}}}
*)

Merge[Apply[Rule]@*Reverse /@ times, List]
Total@*Flatten /@ %
(*  $KernelID -> times of integrals
<|10 -> {{1.3988,  0.33615}},  9 -> {{5.10557, 0.597471}}, 
   8 -> {{5.03329, 3.36767}},  7 -> {{1.4241,  4.75394}}, 
   6 -> {{4.78472, 3.54514}},  5 -> {{1.44249}},
   4 -> {{5.10244}},           3 -> {{4.73389}},
   2 -> {{4.82558}},           1 -> {{4.79167}}|>

<|10 -> 1.73495, 9 -> 5.70304, 8 -> 8.40097, 7 -> 6.17804, 6 -> 8.32986,
   5 -> 1.44249, 4 -> 5.10244, 3 -> 4.73389, 2 -> 4.82558, 1 -> 4.79167|>
*)
```

Unparallelized:

```
(times = Flatten[
    Table[(
     Integrate[(expr SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ]),
      {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}];
     $KernelID) // 
      AbsoluteTiming,
     {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}],
    1]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{20.596, {{0.923452, 0}, {0.242653, 0}, {4.09701, 0}, {0.301539, 
   0}, {0.865541, 0}, {3.20008, 0}, {0.291668, 0}, {1.18621, 
   0}, {0.579081, 0}, {3.30374, 0}, {0.254854, 0}, {0.894277, 
   0}, {0.600397, 0}, {0.670284, 0}, {3.18521, 0}}}
*)

Merge[Apply[Rule]@*Reverse /@ times, List]
Total@*Flatten /@ %
(*
<|0 ->
  {{0.923452,
    0.242653, 4.09701,                  <-- head of column is longest
    0.301539, 0.865541, 3.20008,          ↙  ↓
    0.291668, 1.18621,  0.579081, 3.30374, 
    0.254854, 0.894277, 0.600397, 0.670284, 3.18521}}|>

<|0 -> 20.596|>
*)
```

My guess is that each new value of `m` causes something to be cached or code to be initialized.  You lose this efficiency in parallelization.  For instance, switching the iterators in the first `ParallelTable` above to `{m, 0, lmax}, {l, m, lmax}` cuts the time in half.